different adsoption energies for the same molecule on 1x1 cell and 2x2 cell
When calculating the adsorption energy of glycine on a TiO2 surface, I observed different results for a 1x1 cell functionalized with 1 glycine molecule and a 2x2 cell functionalized with 4 glycine molecules, despite both representing the same coverage.
I used the same K-point mesh for both the unexpanded and the expanded surface.
What could have caused this discrepancy?
PS: this is urgent, I have to present my results in 10 days.

Did you calculate the adsorption energy following the equations here? Also, did you check if the energy is per system/molecule/atom?

As far as I know, even if they have the same material and structure, KPOINTS should be optimized for different cell sizes.
And the periodic conditions of the calculation should also be considered. The TiO2 surface should be large enough compared to the glycine to avoid interference between other glycines.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
